# If I can use SQLite 3 to organize data in python, why should I use classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am going to create a project for my university called Criminal Record System in which I will manage criminal's data and history. Now I stumbled upon the term class. Going through some videos and articles I realized that it is used to save data. So I am confused that if we can use sqlite 3 then why are using classes to organize data.

Comment: A database stores data on **disk**. A class ""stores"" data in **memory**.

Comment: @DeepSpace which is better to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database scope is to **store** data. You use **Classes** to better organize your data in your program.

Think of the database as a warehouse where you store your library and your books. When you need to get some of these books you retrieve them (read from database) and use a Class to organize them when you use it at 'home' (in your program).
Without database when the program is closed you lose all your books. Without classes you have all your books in a mess.

So there is no a 'better' or 'worse'. One does not exclude the other.

You can read this: https://python.swaroopch.com/oop.html

Comment: so that we can use database with classes? Can you provide a rough example.